# How to scaffold DbContext with plural DbSet property names in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-core

**UPDATE 2023:** for modern EF Core versions (.NET 5+), pluralization is enabled by default, as it is shown in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64801660/5112433. The rest of the discussion, while totally relevant at the time given, is nothing more than a history.

**Original question:**

I use `Scaffold-DbContext` command in `Package Manager Console` to create and re-create context and entities for an existed SQL Server database:

```
Scaffold-DbContext -provider EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer -connection "my connection string"
```

It works perfectly except one thing: `DbSet`'s have property names in singular form:

```
public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Request> Request { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<RequestHeader> RequestHeader { get; set; }
}
```

I prefer these names to be in plural form (`Requests` etc.). In addition to web search I checked command syntax:

```
get-Help Scaffold-DbContext -detailed
```

And found nothing to change this behaviour. Here is my `packages.config`:

```
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework.Commands" version="7.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="EntityFramework.Core" version="7.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net46" />
  ...
</packages>
```

How to pluralize `DbSet` names when scaffolding?

**UPDATE 2017-04:** DB First scaffolding pluralization is now possible in Entity Framework Core 1.1. Read my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43320867/5112433) below for details.

Comment: read [this](https://empiricalthoughts.wordpress.com/2015/09/11/entity-framework-7-database-model-pluralization-part-12/) and [this](https://empiricalthoughts.wordpress.com/2015/09/12/entity-framework-7-database-model-pluralization-part-22/)

Comment: Doctor - this is no longer supported, but something like this will appear after RTM

Comment: See my answer here: stackoverflow.com/a/47410837/869033

Comment: @NickN. The `IDesignTimeServices` trick is known since EF Core 1.1. See my answer here =) https://stackoverflow.com/a/43320867/5112433

Comment: The IPluralizer interface is new though, it's way easier now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update for **EntityFrameworkCore 5.0** : TableNames are now automatically pluralized upon scaffolding. (At least with -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer)

Comment: That's it, `Scaffold-DbContext` has pluralizer enabled by default regardless of chosen database provider.

Answer (score 7):

### Short Answer

### 1. Install Package

`Install-Package Bricelam.EntityFrameworkCore.Pluralizer`

### 2. Run `Scaffold-DbContext` Command

`Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "Server=<server>;Database=<dbname>;user id=<userid>;password=<pwd>;" -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Data/EFModels/`

---

### Long Answer:

As pointed out by **@KalinKrastev** in the comments of **@natemcmaster**'s answer. Pluralization in EF Core is possible using a package called `Bricelam.EntityFrameworkCore.Pluralizer` that can be installed using

in the Package Manager Console (PMC) or

`dotnet add package Bricelam.EntityFrameworkCore.Pluralizer`

using Dotnet cli.

After installing the package just use the regular `Scaffold-DbContext` command.

`Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "Server=<server>;Database=<dbname>;user id=<userid>;password=<pwd>;" -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Data/EFModels/ -Force`

[See More About Bricelam's Pluralizer](https://www.bricelam.net/2018/03/02/efcore-pluralization.html)

Comment: Finally, it works for different providers. I scaffolded a PostgreSQL db with the only change in the command: `-Provider Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL`

Answer (score 7):

You can use this command :

```
Scaffold-DbContext "connectionString" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models -UseDatabaseNames -NoPluralize -force
```

You have nuget package before:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design - version 5
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore - version 5
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -version 5
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools - version 5
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational -version 5
```

Comment: -NoPluralize will add Pluralization ?

Comment: pluralization is enabled by default and `-NoPluralize` disables it.

Answer (score 2):

Pluralization is possible in EF Core 1.1. As Rowan Miller [described in its blog](https://romiller.com/2017/02/10/ef-core-1-1-pluralization-in-reverse-engineer/), you need to install the Inflector and implement `IDesignTimeServices` to control pluralization when scaffolding. However, be aware of it:

> We put these services into *.internal namespaces and reserve the right
>   to break the APIs at any point.

So this is why a full code example is not copied to here. This answer is not accepted for the same reason - I prefer to wait until we get a stable API.

Another issue you should consider - this solution is provider-dependent. It works fine with SQL Server (I tested it). Another DBMS provider may not support this API yet. For example, latest [Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL](https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL) 1.1.0 fails on scaffold when custom `IDesignTimeServices` is used.

Answer (score 1):

Pluralization is not supported in EF7 as of RC1. This and other limitations of EF7 scaffolding are being tracked here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4038

Comment: Bricelam's solution works great. Works great! What is still unsolved for me though is, that where they exist more than one capital letters in a table name (e.g. GPSSettings) it generates all except the first letters lowercase (e.g. Gpssettings.cs)

Comment: In case anybody is wondering about what is Bricelam's solution discussed in the @KalinKrastev's comment above, he can look at https://www.bricelam.net/2018/03/02/efcore-pluralization.html

Answer (score 0):

I may be late to the party, but after an upgrade from .net core 3.1 to .net 6, when I used the following command:  dbcontext scaffold "Server=(local);Database=XXXXXX;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models\Entities -c DBContext -f --verbose --no-onconfiguring --startup-project ../XXXX^ it duplicated my entities by generating the singluar form of them. Up until the upgrade de command was giving me the name from the database of the entities so it was not adding the duplicated singular form. I found that using the --no-pluralize option kept the command from generating another entity with singular form. I know they added a default pluralizer in net core 5, but I have no ideea why this worked in preventing the singularization. So Cris Loli's aswer seems to solve my issue. Hope this helps someone solve their issues.