# Asp.net-core Database First Scaffolding

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

Can we control models' names while scaffolding our DB. As I have "Courses" table and I get the model named "Courses" where i want to keep it singular "Course"..?

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34543382/how-to-scaffold-dbcontext-with-plural-dbset-property-names-in-entity-framework-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to scaffold DbContext with plural DbSet property names in Entity Framework Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34543382/how-to-scaffold-dbcontext-with-plural-dbset-property-names-in-entity-framework-c)